# analysis services cube browser

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

I have a cube, 1 fact table, 5 dimension tables.
The fact table have the total amount of sales and I want to analyse what's the country that made more sales.
I can do that, but it's not in order, I want to order the results in the Data Area, I want that the country with most sales to appear in first place.
How can I do that?

[image: Cube]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out. I have to right click the Sales Column and click "Sort Descending"